# On terminal, to disable ALT to show menu tabs

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I prefer on `terminal` using `ALT`-`b` to move to previous word/space (I'm not sure if this is normal behavior of `terminal` but at least on `Gnome` I can do that). But on `unity` pressing `ALT` only shows the menu tabs that are hidden normally. How can I disable that?

I'm on `Quantal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Edit" --> "Keyboard Shortcuts", then disable "Enable menu access keys (such as Alt+F to open the File menu). With this `ALT` still shows menu tabs but you can use combination like `ALT`-`b`.